# Sort gridview column with String.Format{0:C}

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a gridview and it sort perfect as long as I don't change the format. Thus, I changed the format to <%#String.Format("{0:C}", Eval("Amount"))%> for the column and now my column doesn't sort proper anymore. Any suggestions I would greatly appreciate. Also since it sorts perfect when there is no format to currency maybe you have an idea of adding a dollar sign without interfering with the sorting.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try setting a sortexpression for that column? like this -> SortExpression="Amount"

Comment: No. I thought maybe there is a javascript function that can help me do that.

Comment: any specific reason why you want to do it in javascript rather than just setting a property?

Comment: I have only one column that needs sorting all others are fine. But as I am researching more it seems to be a problem with sorting currency column in gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount" SortExpression="Amount" />
```

For TemplateField try something like:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount" SortExpression="Amount">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%#String.Format("{0:C}",Eval("Amount"))%>
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%#String.Format("{0:C}",Eval("Amount"))%></ItemTemplate>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                Amount Collected</HeaderTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

Comment: I have a TemplateField. I love working with BoundField but is not my option.

Comment: Thank you I just need to write the C#. You don't happen to have an example for the protected void GV_Sorting...